# Script-output not showing

Tags: javascript, html

Iv'e insertet a script into 2 different pages. (Just to test it)

[This site missing the menu to the left](http://www.hvidevejs-traktor.dk/brugte-maskiner/)

[This site showing the right things](http://quardonmedia.dk/hvidevejs/)

The script is this:

```
    <script language="JavaScript" src="http://www.altimaskiner.dk/ecatalog/Category.asp?UserID=4823&amp;type=.js"
               type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
           </script>
<div id="Div1">&nbsp;</div>

<div class="ekatalogcat"><script type="text/javascript">
               _PrintViewCat('Div1')
           </script></div>
<script src="http://www.altimaskiner.dk/ecatalog/SalesList.asp?UserID=4823&amp;type=.js" type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<div id="Divtest">&nbsp;</div>

<div class="ekatalog"><script>_PrintView('Divtest')</script></div>
```

Why isn't the menu showing on the second website?
It's sort of "inserting a page into a page"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the code in the first page looks like this:

```
<div class="ekatalogcat"><script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
           _PrintViewCat('Div1')</p>
<p>// ]]&gt;</script></div>
```

You have HTML code in the middle of the script. That causes a syntax error when the script is parsed, so it won't run.

Comment: I tried changing that ealier but didn't help. Tried again now and now it did. Must be some wordpress-thing. Thanks!